# OpenGts with gprmc servlet

Tags: android, gps

i hv trying to tarck the device via open gts using gprmc servlet is
http://192.168.1.99:8080/gprmc/Data?acct=1234&id=test01&code=0xF020&
gprmc=$GPRMC,080701.00,A,3128.7540,N,14257.6714,W,000.0,000.0,180707,,,A*1C

this the structure of the url i am trying in my android app but server does not respondnig but when i am try with gps2opengts app
[image: screen shot with working server]its working so pls tell whre is th error ...?

Comment: how to create $GPRMC xxxxxx type of data url in android and if i want to use it without gps then what to do ?

Comment: it seems no one has any idea. I also am having the same problem

Comment: @DarHamid hey i have solve that problem by creating the string manually from getlatitude(); and all type

Comment: vivek there is another solution and a perfect one. Set deviceID to "test01" where accountID="demo" in eventData table. also in gprmc setting use only localhost and port no. e.g localhost:9090.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing and there is some reading to do.
First read the specs for GPRMC http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#rmc

Next, go to the class Nmea0183 in the source code of OpenGTS and see how the checksum (method calcXORChecksum) at the end of your string is generated.

I did a test and saw that the checksum you are using (1C) is wrong. It sould be 44. It seems that by default OpenGTS does not ignore the checksum if you have not appended it at the end of the string, so you always have to calculate it in your android app and add it at the end. If the checksum is not correct, the request is dropped and nothing is logged.

Finally, make sure you are using correct date and time in the GPRMC string, otherwise you will have difficulty locating it in the reports at the web app. For example, in the string you sent, it seems that the date is 18 July 2007 and the time is GMT 08:07:01.

Hope it helps and looking forward to your app. I could really use it.

This is what I did in the main method of Nmea0183 (I commented everything else).

```
String gprmc = "$GPRMC,080701.00,A,3128.7540,N,14257.6714,W,000.0,000.0,180707,,,A*44";
int cs = calcXORChecksum(gprmc, false);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(cs));
Nmea0183 n;

n = new Nmea0183(gprmc, false);
Print.sysPrintln("$GPRMC   : " + gprmc);
Print.sysPrintln("      ==>: " + n.toGPRMC());
Print.sysPrintln("NMEA-0183: \n" + n);
```

Comment: i hv recently built a solution in android client side with the help off some $GPRMC protocal set and it works fine on both side 
anyways i will check your answer and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks, I also finised my android client for OpenGTS. If I do not use it for a potential client, I will publish it on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek,

While you mave have succeeded in creating gprmc string in android, your server still may not accept the request because your current request contains `id` as http parameter however it should be `dev`.  OpenGTS has `acct` for account string and `dev` for device string and `gprmc` parameter name for gprmc string.  And you can directly get gprmc string using Android API - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html

Comment: hi dipti i had resolved the issue and the link you have posted above does not shown any relevant method to get gprmc string.